What is the name of this National Geographic TV special on the creation of Earth?
Some time ago, give or take 5 years, I was watching a documentary on Nat Geo or a similar channel that might have bought it. It was a documentary on how the Earth was formed, from the Big Bang. It explained how high levels of oxygen enabled everything to grow twice as large as they would today.
It was a pretty comprehensive doccie, with some decent graphics. It was long, maybe 1-2 hrs. I cannot remember the narrator. There were no actors, as everything was CGI. Like a video game.
I have tried to find the doccie, but I cannot find it.
If it helps, the style of the video was reminiscent of another doccie showing various animals and insects, enlarged or shrunk to the average of the competition and made to compete in "Olympic" style games. Thats a bit off topic, the creation doccie is the one I'm after 

it's not Planet Earth. as far as i can recall, no "real" features were used. it did discuss the ice-caps etc... but it wasn't Planet Earth. I would remember Sir David Attenborough if it was

Was the entire episode CGI? Did the movie also talk about evolution or just solely the creation of earth? Also, do you know if the BBC Life channel only airs BBC productions? Was the documentary you watched produced by BBC or could it have been produced by National Geographic or some other company?

@Movers as far as i can recall, it was solely BBC. had the logo and everything. A BBC production during the credits. it was CGI. bit hazy on that. and it discussed how the ice caps melted, volcanoes erupted causing ash to form and stabilise the atmosphere, releasing oxygen in the water and making fish so on and so on. like a creation and evolution doccie.

How much evolution was shown? Like all the way to modern times, Jurassic age, etc.

hmm.... i don't think it went all the way to the present. it was setting up the basis of how the Earth was born, and how animals and such were created by a process of evolution. if i am not mistaken, it might've commented on how apes climbed down the trees and become man, then moved out of Africa. it was a long doccie, it even covered the dinos and the extinction, how that affected the further evolution of the organisms today. but not so much technology and industrial age etc. just until the dawn of man/recorded history

National Geographic: The Story of Earth (TV 2011) ? Are you sure that it was a BBC production?

@Mazura yours seems the likeliest candidate. once i have access to YouTube, i can verify. could've sworn it was a BBC production... to ere is human

@Mazura thank you very much. this is the show. but golly, have i made a mess of the question! do i edit it? or leave it? and btw, you may answer and i'll accept it

Will post Mazura's answer to help others out.
It is National Geographic: The Story of Earth (TV 2011)  as I have watched it this past weekend and it was definitely this one. It covers the creation of the Earth from the Big Bang and covers how the atmosphere stabilised, how sea creatures came onto land and eventually how we were evolved. For anyone who is looking to learn someone from evolution, or anybody looking for material to show to a class, I highly recommend this piece.
I apologise to all for incorrectly marking this as a BBC production, when it was in fact a Nat Geo production. Thanks to all for the help

There's no need for him to post the answer now anyway.

isn't it helpful to do so? or can we close this? or just leave it with the changes?

Sure, it's totally fine to provide an answer for solving the question. There's nothing wrong with it. All I'm saying is that there isn't really a need for Mazura to provide the exact same answer again.

cool. i'll edit it to fix that statement

I think this may have been the Ice Age Giants series BBC produced in 2013.
I remember watching it at the time and being struck by the notion that atmospheric conditions during the Ice Age were one of the contributing factors to how mammals were able to grow so large, so that part rings a bell somewhat.
I don't remember it lingering for too long on the origins of creation itself, it was more about the post-cambrian beasts: but it was certainly CGI as far as the animals were concerned.
